# Mixamo animation transfer animation to another model

Tags: mixamo

I'm following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qd-2CxIk2WQ&t=12s) that uses a character from [pmndrs market](https://market.pmnd.rs/) to animate using Mixamo. I want to use a different model. Here is the model from [SketchFab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/hisoka-hxh-f85b3502129c41b2a0dc24b16a49a8ee).

What I did.

- Downloaded both GLTF and FBX models from SketchFab and imported the GLTF file to blender.
  [image]
- Uploaded FBX file to Mixamo for auto-rigging and select animation.

[image]

- Download the animated FBX file from Maximo and Import it in Blender.
  [image]
- **PS:** If you notice the original sketchfab model doesn't have pose or animation properties, unlike the Armature.
- I renamed the animation name to Run. I then selected my Original Sketchfab model and added the Run 'animation' to it. Resulting in creating a new animation property layer with Run as it's child.
  [image]

I tried exporting the original file as a compressed GLTF file to my 3D scene but couldn't play or even find the animations.